# Certificates not on phone Nokia S40 Error

Tags: nokia, nokia-s40

I ve deployed the application with the keystore with certificated added.

I generated the keystore and cert using the keytool eclipse plugin.

i installed

Now the issue is upon installing it on device there is an error message like this "Certificate not on phone or sim".

Then installed the cert on device as instructed here (http://www.nokia.com/in-en/support/troubleshooting/?action=singleFAQ&caseid=FA139228_en_US).

Still i'm getting the same error mesg as "Certificate not on phone or sim".

Answer (score 0):

I use a verysign certificate on Netbeans, and always works. Can you try to put on teh security option from the preferences menu of a project.